# Cronjob Pausing between 00:00 and 01:00

Tags: webserver, cron, cron-task

I know, there are many contents about cronjob. But i'm uncertain.

I need a Cron that run all 5 minutes. This Cron shouldn't run between 00:00 and 01:00 (in the night)

My cron

```
*/5 01-23 * * * balbalabalabal > aaa
```

Is this right?

Running this cron at 23.05, 23.10....23.55 and start again at 01:00?

best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I tested this.

The Cron runs at 23.05, 23.10..... until 23.55. 
Then pausing and the first Cronjob start again at 01.00